# Eclipse - "main cannot be resolved or is not a field" (Android App programming)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I've got a problem with Eclipse. I use the ADT to develop Android apps directly in Eclipse. But right after creating a new project, I got an error in my "MainActivity.java"-file.

I googled and everywhere its said that I  have to import an ".R" class from my project folder, which didnt work for me. I also completetely redownloaded Eclipse+ADT in one package this morning.

The line which gives the error is the following:

setContentView(R.layout.main);

Without the "import com.example.myapp.R" statement I've got the same error. Cleaning and rebuilding also didnt have any effect.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: remove `import android.R;`

Comment: There is no import android.R

Answer (score 0):

Try to type `R r;` in your code. Hover your mouse over the 'R' and Eclipse will say "`R cannot be resolved to a type`". Click import `R (com.example.myapp)`. If this doesn't work then check for the folder `gen` to say Generated Java Files. Also check to see if they have the classes inside.

Answer (score 0):

R.layout.main refers to a layout XML file in your "res/layout" directory. This seems like the layout file you are trying to reference is named something else. 
.
You just need to make sure that your referencing the correct layout in your `onCreate` method.

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Renaming it into the specific XML File (in my case activity_player) went fine, but now I got a much worse problem.
I saw that almost all other files in the "myapp" Package in the src-Folder got errors, most of them even like 10-15. It wasnt instantly visible before but now after trying to run I see them (independently from the activity_Player fix, because when creating a new project I also got them. 

I think there has to be something from with my files or something, because that many errors cant be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Post the main.xml. Make sure you import your application's R file and not android.R. Restart eclipse, do a clean up by going to your menu Project-> Clean , refresh and tell us if it is fixed.